# Email Body for a custom report in Business Central

Tags: dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

I have created a custom (.RDL) report in SQL Server Report Builder and an AL extension that emails this report as a PDF attachment from an action on a custom page & table in Business Central. This is working fine. My question is about the email body text. At the moment I have hardcoded a few sentences (e.g.) 'Please see attached document etc...' in the codeunit in the extension. Ideally I would like the users to be able to edit the email body text as and when needed in BC without me having to change the extension. Is there a way that an email body can be saved in Business Central for user editing? And can that email body be loaded programmatically by a codeunit prior to sending the email?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do what you are asking using.

Business Central does exactly this when e.g. sending Sales Invoices.

You should have a look at the [`Report Selections`](https://github.com/StefanMaron/MSDyn365BC.Code.History/blob/master/BaseApp/Source/Base%20Application/ReportSelections.Table.al) table. It has a procedure `GetEmailBodyTextForCust` which does the swap to the relevant report layout for the email body. It is used in the procedure `SendEmailToCustDirectly`.

Note that the report layout used for email body must be a Word layout.